# Display Only One Record That May Or May Not Have Children

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been stuck on this issue for a while now. I'm really close I think, but there's something I'm missing.

A Transaction can have zero or many TransactionErrors. I am trying to display all Transactions only once, and I'm also trying to display only the latest error message if there is one.

```
    SELECT [Transaction].[TransactionID]
      ,[FileName]
      ,[DestinationSystem]
      ,[CreatedOn]
      ,LEFT([TransactionError].[ErrorMessage], 300) AS LatestErrorMessage --Gets only the first 300 characters of the error message
FROM [WM01DB].[dbo].[Transaction]
    INNER JOIN SourceSystem ON SourceSystem.SourceSystemId = Transaction.SourceSystemId
    LEFT JOIN TransactionError ON TransactionError.TransactionId = Transaction.TransactionId
WHERE Transaction.CreatedOn >= '2014-08-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND Transaction.CreatedOn < '2014-09-02 00:00:00.000'
    ORDER BY [CreatedOn], [Transaction].[TransactionID]
```

When I run this query, I get most of the results I want, but I get duplicate transactions because these transactions have multiple TransactionErrors. It looks like this...

```
TransactionID       FileName                    DestinationSystem   CreatedOn           LatestErrorMessage
18124           201408131541517937_DC_TEST_3339376-4.1.xml  TEST            2014-08-18 18:31:19.993     U_BOL and Tracking Number are blank
18124           201408131541517937_DC_TEST_3339376-4.1.xml  TEST            2014-08-18 18:31:19.993     FRT_CHG_TYPE is blank
18125           201408111521484448_DC_TEST_3339375-2.1.xml  TEST            2014-08-19 16:04:58.467     NULL
18126           201408111521484448_DC_TEST_3339375-2.1.xml  TEST            2014-08-19 16:09:00.467     NULL
```

Ugh... Bad looking code block...

As you can see, there are duplicate TransactionIDs as demonstrated with 18124. I would like 18124 to display only once with the latest error message. The only way to get the latest error message would be to use the latest TransactionErrorID for a particular TransactionID...

Please help! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar solution to Krishnraj Rana.  However, I think that you need to avoid having the rowid filter in the WHERE clause because that will make if behave like an inner join:

```
; with Errors as 
(SELECT  [ErrorMessage]
        , Row_Number() over (Partition By TransactionId order by TransactionErrorId Desc) as id
    FROM TransactionError
)

    SELECT [Transaction].[TransactionID]
      ,[FileName]
      ,[DestinationSystem]
      ,[CreatedOn]
      ,LEFT([ErrorMessage], 300) AS LatestErrorMessage --Gets only the first 300 characters of the error message
FROM [WM01DB].[dbo].[Transaction]
    INNER JOIN SourceSystem ON SourceSystem.SourceSystemId = Transaction.SourceSystemId
    LEFT JOIN Errors ON TransactionError.TransactionId = Transaction.TransactionId
        and errors.id = 1
WHERE Transaction.CreatedOn >= '2014-08-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND Transaction.CreatedOn < '2014-09-02 00:00:00.000'
    ORDER BY [CreatedOn], [Transaction].[TransactionID]
```

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't get this query to run.

Comment: I guessed at the column names, what error did you get?

Comment: Whatever the issue was, it must have been me. This is definitely the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using **ROW_NUMBER()** with **PARTITION BY** clause like this -

```
SELECT [Transaction].[TransactionID]
    ,[FileName]
    ,[DestinationSystem]
    ,[CreatedOn]
    ,LEFT([TransactionError].[ErrorMessage], 300) AS LatestErrorMessage --Gets only the first 300 characters of the error message
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY [Transaction].[TransactionID] ORDER BY [CreatedOn]
            ,[Transaction].[TransactionID] DESC
        ) AS SrNo
FROM [WM01DB].[dbo].[Transaction]
INNER JOIN SourceSystem ON SourceSystem.SourceSystemId = TRANSACTION.SourceSystemId
LEFT JOIN TransactionError ON TransactionError.TransactionId = TRANSACTION.TransactionId
WHERE TRANSACTION.CreatedOn >= '2014-08-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND TRANSACTION.CreatedOn < '2014-09-02 00:00:00.000'
    AND SrNo = 1
ORDER BY [CreatedOn]
    ,[Transaction].[TransactionID]
```

Comment: This `SrNo` in where clause will error out as this is not visible to this query yet, you will need to use this in an outer query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.[TransactionID]
      ,A.[FileName]
      ,A.[DestinationSystem]
      ,A.[CreatedOn]
      ,A.LatestErrorMessage
FROM (
SELECT [Transaction].[TransactionID]
      ,[FileName]
      ,[DestinationSystem]
      ,[CreatedOn]
      ,LEFT([TransactionError].[ErrorMessage], 300) AS LatestErrorMessage --Gets only the first 300 characters of the error message
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Transaction].[TransactionID] ORDER BY [CreatedOn] DESC) rn
FROM [WM01DB].[dbo].[Transaction]
INNER JOIN SourceSystem    ON SourceSystem.SourceSystemId    = [Transaction].SourceSystemId
                           AND   [Transaction].CreatedOn >= '2014-08-01 00:00:00.000'
                           AND   [Transaction].CreatedOn <  '2014-09-02 00:00:00.000'
LEFT JOIN TransactionError ON TransactionError.TransactionId = [Transaction].TransactionId
  )A 
WHERE A.rn = 1 
ORDER BY A.[CreatedOn], A.[TransactionID]
```

Comment: The order in the partition clause should be `TransactionErrorId desc`

Answer (score 1):

Also using `row_number()` but picking last `TransactionErrorId` as requested (and assuming at least SQL Server 2005):

```
with x as (
    select
        t.[TransactionId],
        [FileName],
        [DestinationSytem],
        [CreatedOn],
        e.[ErrorMessage],
        row_number() over (
            partition by t.[TransactionId],
            order by e.[TransactionErrorId] desc
        ) rn
    from
        [wm01db].[dbo].[Transaction] t
            inner join
        [dbo].[SourceSystem] s
            on t.SourceSystemId = s.SourceSytemId
            left outer join
        [dbo].[TransactionError] e
            on e.TransactionId = t.TransactionId
    where
        t.CreatedOn >= '2014-08-01 00:00:00.000' and
        t.CreatedOn < '2014-09-02 00:00:00.000'
) select
    [TransactionId],
    [FileName],
    [DestinationSytem],
    [CreatedOn],
    left([ErrorMessage], 300) as LastErrorMessage
from
    x
where
    rn = 1
order by
    [CreatedOn],
    [TransactionId] ;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to get me any different results than my original. I'm still seeing the duplicates I showed before.

Comment: Oops, missed out the `where rn = 1`